# Extjs add item to extended class

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Using Extjs 5 I am defining my custom toolbar:

```
Ext.define('Core.toolbar.view.ToolbarView',
{
        extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',

        dock: 'top',
        items: [
        {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'add'
        },
        {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'remove'          
        }]

});
```

Now I want to use it:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ToolbarView',
{
        extend: 'Core.toolbar.view.ToolbarView',

        items: [
        {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'ADDING AN OTHER BUTTON'
        }]

});

Ext.create('MyApp.view.ToolbarView');
```

Using `items` property I am overriding the old items with the new item, but I do not want to do it. I want to add third button.

Is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd make use of `initComponent`, like this ([example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t3h)):

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.define('Core.toolbar.view.ToolbarView', {
      extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',

      dock: 'top',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'add'
      }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'remove'
      }]

    });

    Ext.define('MyApp.view.ToolbarView', {
      extend: 'Core.toolbar.view.ToolbarView',
      initComponent: function() {

        this.callParent();
        this.add({
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'ADDING AN OTHER BUTTON'
        });
      }

    });

    Ext.create('MyApp.view.ToolbarView', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    Ext.create('MyApp.view.ToolbarView', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: with your solution every time I create the MyApp.view.ToolbarView component add a new button. So if I create 10 components I see 10 "ADDING AN OTHER BUTTON" text. You can try it by adding           Ext.create('MyApp.view.ToolbarView', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        }); in your fiddle

Comment: Sorry about that... check the fiddle again for the updated version.  (That's why sometimes you don't mess with the private variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onClassExtended` on your core toolbar and set a `onBeforeCreated` hook, for example:

```
onClassExtended: function (cls, data, hooks) {
    var onBeforeClassCreated = hooks.onBeforeCreated,
        Cls = this,
        xArray = Ext.Array;

    hooks.onBeforeCreated = function (clss, dataa) {

        dataa.items = xArray.from(Cls.prototype.items).concat(xArray.from(dataa.items));

        onBeforeClassCreated.call(this, clss, dataa, hooks);

    };
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t3i

Comment: Nice trick, does literally what the asker wanted. But from forward-looking point of view, they probably would not want adding extra items to the end of the array hardcoded in a class called "**Core**.toolbar.view.ToolbarView".

Answer (score 0):

When you provide [`items`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-items) on extending an `Ext.container.Container` (or creating an instance of it), by default, any previously specified `items` will be overridden, indeed. There is no out-of-the-box logic in place to merge them — simply because Ext JS does not know *how* you want them merged: whether you want the latter `items` to go after the former ones, or before, or somehow in the middle, or you want overriding. You need to tell Ext JS what you want explicitly.

So, here is yet another approach:

```
Ext.define('Core.toolbar.view.ToolbarView', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    buildItems: function() {
        return [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'add'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'remove'
            }
        ];
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = this.buildItems();
        this.callParent();
    }
});
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ToolbarView', {
    extend: 'Core.toolbar.view.ToolbarView',
    buildItems: function() {
        return this.callParent().concat([
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'ADDING AN OTHER BUTTON'
            }
        ]);
    }
});
Ext.create('MyApp.view.ToolbarView');
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t48